# Remove out excess spaces from string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I have written program for removing excess spaces from string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void RemoveExcessSpaces(std::string &s) {
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    while (s[i] == ' ')s.erase(s.begin() + i);
    while (s[i] != ' ' && i < s.length())i++;
  }
  if (s[s.length() - 1] == ' ')s.pop_back();
}
int main() {
  std::string s("  this is   string  ");
  RemoveExcessSpaces(s);
  std::cout << "\"" << s << "\"";
  return 0;
}
```

One thing is not clear to me. This `while (s[i] == ' ')s.erase(s.begin() + i);` should remove every space in string, so the output would be `thisisstring`, but I got correct output which is `this is string`.

Could you explain me why program didn't remove one space between `this` and `is` and why I got the correct output?

Note: I cannot use auxiliary strings.

Comment: Split the entire while loops on separate lines with the conditions and the loop bodies, and use your favorite debugger for stepping through the code and observing the values in variables. Debuggers are the most important tools for developers.

Comment: Hint: Your loop increments `i` in two different places. Think about how those increments interact with each other

Comment: if we just ask questions without even trying to solve it, we get feedback "you haven't even tried it, do it on you own and then ask specific question", but when we do it on our own and finish it completely, then we get feedback "use debugger on your own"...

Comment: @273K I don't know how to run debugger outside main function...

Comment: "step into" is the debugger function that will follow the path of execution into the RemoveExcessSpaces function from the main function.  Which debugger are you using?

Comment: "Step into" or simply set breakpoint on a line in the you are interested in.

Comment: I'm using codeblocks working eniveronment, I don't know which debugger

Comment: [Debugging with Code::Blocks](https://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks)

Comment: The first `while` must check for  `i < s.length()` too. The string might end with `' '`.

Comment: Using `s.erase` is hugely inefficient. It would be better to copy characters to the front as you scan the string and trim it once at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when your **last while loop** finds the space between your characters (this is) control pass to increment part of your **for loop** which will increase the value of **int i** then it will point to next character of given string that is i(this **i**s string) that's why there is space between (**this is**).

Comment: correct output is `this is string` this code removed all spaces

Answer (score 0):

Your second `while` loop will break when `s[i]==' '`. But then your `for` loop will increment `i` and `s[i]` for that `i` will be skipped. This will happen for every first space character after each word.